# Same PHP JSON doesnt return values depending on URL

Tags: php, json, wordpress, foreach

I am trying to return decoded JSON values in a foreach loop. It works, but when I change it to a different JSON URL source it won't return any data. I'm aware that I have ended `$raceDetails` with `[0]` for the broken code as I would like to access the data directly in each of the increments. I have tried specifying data one level deeper `Races[0]->Circuit` and it still doesn't return any data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Working Code

```
$url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$nextRace = json_decode($json);
$raceDetails = $nextRace->MRData->RaceTable->Races[0]->Results;

foreach($raceDetails as $race){
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th class="r-pos">' . $race->position . '</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
}
```

### Broken Code

```
    $url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/2016.json";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $nextRace = json_decode($json);
    $raceDetails = $nextRace->MRData->RaceTable->Races[0];

    foreach($raceDetails as $race){
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th class="r-pos">' . $race->Circuit->date . '</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: `Races[0]` returns single object.

Comment: And `Circuit` property has no `date` attribute. Learn to debug your  code.

Answer (score 1):

It must be

```
$raceDetails = $nextRace->MRData->RaceTable->Races;

foreach($raceDetails as $race){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th class="r-pos">' . $race->date . '</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but how would i write this if I wanted to increment within the foreach? e.g. Following the first codes JSON file `MRData->RaceTable->Races` so that would go through each Races (0,1,2,3...) then `Results->[0,2,3,4,5...]->number`  So it would return every Race with every Result -> number

Comment: @Connor I want to help you, but I don't understand what you are trying to say in the previous comment.